# jOOQ fetching custom SQL into mapper

Tags: scala, jooq, mapper

I encouter one problem using [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org). Can I include dynamic column to `mapper/table` ?

#### SQL

```sql
CREATE TABLE "PartnerCategory"
    (
      "ID" uuid NOT NULL,
      "Name" character varying(200),
      "Description" character varying,
      "ParentId" uuid,
      "Visible" boolean,
      CONSTRAINT "PartnerCategory_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
    )
    WITH (
      OIDS=FALSE
    );
    ALTER TABLE "PartnerCategory"
      OWNER TO postgres;
```

and

```
val SQL_CTE =
    """
      WITH recursive cte1 as (
      select pc."ID", pc."Name", pc."Description", pc."ParentId", pc."Visible", CAST(pc."Name" as text) as Path
        from "PartnerCategory" pc where pc."ParentId" IS NULL
        union
      select pc."ID", pc."Name", pc."Description", pc."ParentId", pc."Visible", ct.Path || ' | ' || CAST(pc."Name" as text) as Path
        from "PartnerCategory" pc
        join cte1 ct on pc."ParentId" = ct."ID"  )
    select ct."ID", ct."Name", ct."Description", ct."ParentId", ct."Visible", ct.Path from cte1 ct
    """.stripMargin
```

#### Code

In query above we have all columns from `PartnerCategory` and one column which is dynamic `Path`.
Previously to get this all working I had manaully iterate over result:

```
val x: Seq[PartnerCategory] = for (i <- abcd.asScala)
    yield PartnerCategory(
        UUID.fromString(i.getValue(0).toString),
        i.getValue(1).toString,
        i.getValue(2).toString,
        i.getValue(3) match {
          case null => None
          case f: UUID => Some(UUID.fromString(f.toString))
        },
        false,
        i.getValue(5).toString)
```

I have custom mapper for this table:

```
class PartnerCategoryMapper extends RecordMapper[PartnercategoryRecord, PartnerCategory] {
  def map(r: PartnercategoryRecord): PartnerCategory = {
    val pc = PartnerCategory(r.getId, r.getName, r.getDescription, Some(r.getParentid), r.getVisible, "")
    pc.IsNew = false
    pc
  }
}
```

My model looks like:

```
case class PartnerCategory(var ID: UUID,var Name: String, var Description: String, var ParentId: Option[UUID], var Visible: Boolean, Path: String)
```

I tried to write better code and I found that this works almost perfect. I just loose information about dynamic column `Path`:

```
val F = model.jooq.tables.Partnercategory.PARTNERCATEGORY
val mapper = new PartnerCategoryMapper()
val record = new PartnercategoryRecord()
ctx.fetch(SQL_CTE).into(F).map(mapper).asScala
```

#### Question

How can I do fetch into another mapper with 1 extra column, for example like this:

```
class PartnerCategoryMapperDynamic extends RecordMapper[PartnercategoryRecordWithPath, PartnerCategory] {
  def map(r: PartnercategoryRecordWithPath): PartnerCategory = {
    val pc = PartnerCategory(r.getId, r.getName, r.getDescription, Some(r.getParentid), r.getVisible, r.getPath)
    pc.IsNew = false
    pc
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to let go of some of the typesafety, you could write:

```
class PartnerCategoryMapperDynamic 
extends RecordMapper[Record, PartnerCategory] {
  def map(r: Record): PartnerCategory = {
    val pc = PartnerCategory(
      r.getValue(PARTNER_CATEGORY.ID), 
      r.getValue(PARTNER_CATEGORY.NAME), 
      r.getValue(PARTNER_CATEGORY.DESCRIPTION), 
      Some(r.getValue(PARTNER_CATEGORY.PARENTID)), 
      r.getValue(PARTNER_CATEGORY.VISIBLE),
      if (r.field(PARTNER_CATEGORY_WITH_PATH.PATH) != null)
        r.getValue(PARTNER_CATEGORY_WITH_PATH.PATH)
      else
        ""
    )
    pc.IsNew = false
    pc
  }
}
```

Comment: But PARTNERCATEGORY.PATH is dynamically calculated column?